# Windows didn't create a "System Reserved" partition. Does this matter? How it will impact my computer?

Tags: windows

I freshly installed Windows 10 through USB drive.

But Windows didn't create a "System Reserved" partition.

My drive only has a "C: drive" partition and "Recovery" Partition.

How it will impact my computer?

My system is running fine though.

[image]

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, Can I manually create a system reserved partition and transfer information in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to install Windows is to let it allocate the partitions,
but pre-allocating the partition also works as well.

If you format the whole disk into one unallocated space during the install,
then Windows will create a System Reserved partition that will contain the
boot code.

If instead you created a partition and formatted it, then chose that
partition to install Windows, you will not get a System Reserved partition.
The boot information will in this case be included in the `C:` partition.

You evidently chose the second method when installing Windows.
The boot code is a bit more vulnerable to corruption if it resides
on your work partition, rather than isolated in the
System Reserved partition, but it will work just fine.

Your computer is fine and is fully functional, no worries.